# db4o - Performance issue where a list of children each of which refrences his parent

Tags: parent-child, db4o

I have a Parent / Child relation as follows and I use C# and db4o for persistence.

```cs
class Parent{
    List<Child> children = new List<Child>();
}

class Child{
    Parent parent;
}
```

It takes long time to retrieve objects of type `Child`. 
Is there something I missed?

Comment: Infinite loop? Can you post a very short, complete example somewhere?

Comment: it is not exactly an infinite loop. To retrieve a list of 30 children, It takes about a minute to response.

Comment: I changed the **infinite loop** phrase to **long time**.

Comment: hmm...no clue. I need a running example

Comment: I made a short example and ran it but it was OK. after some investigation, I found that poor performance was due to string operations. I searched and found that some DLLs should be added for optimization but that one did not solve my problem too. It seems that all the objects are instantiated and then the comparison applied.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the graph your data encode. But it look like your are loading the complet / large portion of the graph for each object.

Without special configuration Db4o load all the objects that have a relation with the object that is load.

If you want lazy loading you should look at the [transparent activation](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.0/java/tutorial/docs/TransparentActivation.html). It require a litte more of configuration.

Comment: I used lazy loading and just load a portion of an object but it seemed for a string comparison, all engaged objects were instantiated. After that I moved to Fluent NHibernate and Now it is OK.